# write file path only one time even if there are more then one string with the file within a recursive search

Tags: python

I'm doing a recursive search in a directory. Every thing is happening accordingly except for the fact that my script is writing the file path for every string it finds within a file. I want the script to write the file's path only one time and move on the next file.

Here is the code:

```
srcn_path = input('   Enter directory: ')
files = os.walk(srcn_path)
print ()

scrNumber = input('   Enter SCR number: ')
print ()

for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk(srcn_path, topdown=True):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(filepath, 'w') as currentfile:
            for line in currentfile:
                if scrNumber in line:
                    file = open("Tag_In_Header.txt", "a")
                    file.write(filepath+' "'+scrNumber+'" found\n')
                    file.close()
```

```
Example of actual result of my code is:

d:\dog\cat\deer.txt string found
d:\dog\cat\deer.txt string found
d:\dog\cat\lion\tiger\pig.txt string found
d:\dog\cat\lion\tiger\pig.txt string found

Expected result:

d:\dog\cat\deer.txt string found
d:\dog\cat\lion\tiger\pig.txt string found
```

Comment: break in the inner for

Comment: Christian I just noticed that you supplied the correct answer to my question/problem. I'm new to stackoverflow. I missed your comment. Thank you so much.